# problem display button edit in form for the specific user

Tags: php, mysql

im facing a problem for displaying edit,delete buttons for the comments that belongs to that user ,,,this is my code and dont get it where is the problem and how to solve it (because like this: edit and delete buttons will show up for the all comments !

````
$results = mysqli_query($c, "SELECT * from comments where idpub=".$_GET['com']."and iduser=".$_SESSION['id']);
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) { 
?>
<?php echo $rows['username'];  ?>
<?php echo $rows['textcom']; ?>

      <a href="comment2.php?edit=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" class="edit_btn" >Edit</a>
<a href="pubf.php?del=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" class="del_btn">Delete</a>
<?php } ?>```
````

Comment: Why You have downvote my answer? AS You have accepted my answer you have to upvote it. Please upvote this answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to check logged in User's Id and the User id of Comment who add that comment. If Both ids are the same then display those buttons.

```
$results = mysqli_query($c, "SELECT * from comments where idpub=".$_GET['com']."and iduser=".$_SESSION['id']);
```

based on the above code I think you are fetching all the comments of user id which is store in a session, so it shows edit delete buttons with each comment. So You have to change your code like below.

```
    $results = mysqli_query($c, "SELECT * from comments where idpub=".$_GET['com']);
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) { 
?>
<?php echo $rows['username'];  ?>
<?php echo $rows['textcom']; ?>
<?php if($_SESSION['id'] == $rows['userid']){ ?>


<a href="comment2.php?edit=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" class="edit_btn" 
>Edit</a>
<a href="pubf.php?del=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" class="del_btn">Delete</a>
<?php } }?>
```

Comment: Hello @yolo Why you have downvote my answer as you have accept my answer. Please upvote it.